# D/A converter with 0.4 up to 4V voltage output

Tags: switches, dac

I have this circuit:

http://www.malgefragt.net/images/image.php?di=LV13

I want to have as output:

```
BCD    Voltage
0        0.4V
1        0.8V
.
.
9         4V
```

My circuit actually doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You only told us what you expect it to do, not what it actually does. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a digital-to-analog converter using an R2R ladder. Whether you like it or not, the voltage range for the output is determined by the full range of binary inputs, 0 to 15 rather than 0 to 9. The value of the LSB is 4V/16 = 0.25V rather than 4V/10 and the output voltage for a digital input of 9 (decimal) will be 2.25V.

To get the results you expected you need to increase the supply voltage from 4V to 6.4V, except that you can't get any voltage out with all of the switches open.

Comment: It can be fixed by adding a fith bit that is always `1` to introduce the offset.

Comment: @jippie I don't think it's that easy. If we add a fifth bit and want the value of the LSB to be 0.4V then the supply voltage increases to 12.8V. The value of the second bit (the least significant bit that is not hardwired but is connected to a switch) will be 0.8V. The result is that decimal 0 (binary 00001) would produce 0.4V but decimal 1 (binary 00011) would give 1.2V.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize that would be an effect too. Oh well, I guess if you can make a 4V power supply or a 6.4V power supply, then a extra 0.4V power supply shouldn't be an issue. Or of course an opamp sum circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the design problem with a 4 bit demux with custom R controlled voltage on each of 10 outputs.